# show logo in html without showing url in source

Tags: php, html

i am trying to display an image in HTML using:

```
<img src="/logo.php?seq=5" />
```

then logo.php looks like:

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * from reseller where sequence = '".$_GET["seq"]."' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

echo '<img src="http://www.integradigital.co.uk/customer/'.$result["logo"].'" />';
?>
```

but its not working - whats the best way to do this so the user seeing the image cannot look at the URL of the image. if they open the image in its own window i want them to see something like http://www.domain.com/logo.php?seq=5 ???

Comment: Why don't you place a div instead and set logo as background image so that it will not be straight forward URL to show.

Comment: i thought about that but if the user looks in the CSS it will show the url

Comment: Define "cannot look at the URL."  Even if it's referenced in CSS, the user can still look at it if they want to.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: its easy, just base64 encode your urls ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `readfile()` to read the image in the image.php:

```
// Read URL from database
$sql    = "SELECT * from reseller where sequence = '" . $_GET["seq"] . "'";
$rs     = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($rs);

// Generate path
$path = '/customer/' . $result["logo"];

// Set proper headers
$headers = get_headers( $path );

foreach( $headers as $h )
    if( strpos( $h, 'Content-Type:' ) !== false )
        header( $h );

// Send file to user
readfile( $path );
```

Then PHP reads the right logo and outputs it, the user won't be able to see the real path. You can link the logo like you proposed:

```
<img src="/logo.php?seq=5" alt="Logo">
```

Comment: You should also send a proper image header.

Comment: so if i use this in image.php or logo.php what do i use in the menu.php file?

Comment: You can just link it like you proposed: `<img src="/logo.php?seq=5" />`

Comment: im getting text like: ‰PNG  IHDRè½6‘tEXtSoftwareAdobe ImageReadyqÉe<�yQIDATxÚì]`]eÙ~Î¼;7{5iÒ=è¢tRö,”)K@AD6((ü ‚,EA™Ê] Œ²)JÝ{7ÍNî<ëßïÜ$7¹7éÂš§¹óÜs¾ó=ïû¼ó“ÇAïÖ»õnßÎMå$Iê‰Þí»ºõ4yÿ €ön½Û·dÛz]êæsN–½ ½[/Ð¾ IÛ¡”e—ÓÞg0   ...and much more... when i echo $path its the right URL though

Comment: Try it again with the proper headers I added, that should solve it.

Comment: Warning: finfo_file() [function.finfo-file]: Failed identify data 0:(null) in /home/reseller/public_html/logo.php on line 13

Comment: im getting these errors when i go to logo.php?seq=5 but on the menu.php page where i have <img src="/logo.php?seq=5" /> its just showing a blank square - no imagae

Comment: Are you sure this is the right absolute path to the file? It might be something like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/customers/'` instead.

Comment: I get the feeling they are actually separate sites, and the one that contains the actual images is separate hosting, he might need the full url (which I think `readfile` still supports).

Comment: That would indeed be very bad. Are the logos on the same server as your script @charlie?

Comment: yes they are 2 seperate sites - i have put the $path with the domain at the start

Comment: same server - 2 sites

Comment: @charlie Then in logo.php you need to use the path to the site that the images are stored on, preferable the full local path. (/home/reseller/public_html/ ?)

Comment: If they are on the same server, does one site have access to the files of the other? Is open_basedir activated?

Comment: im not sure - its not my server its with a hosting company

Comment: and no the sites dont have access to each other

Comment: Look at it now, it fetches the headers from the remote site.